# Letsencrypt Timeout reasons

Tags: linux, timeout, letsencrypt, certbot

I am having problems when renewing my letsencrypt certificate.
I am using nginx and certbot for renewal.

Output is the following:

```
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf 
produced an unexpected error:
Failed authorization procedure. example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: 
The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: 
Fetching http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/AUStfngCwdGL8Hel2jR0jG4wLZZjXi-s7AypLNWrECo: 
Timeout. Skipping.
```

.
Most peculiar my nginx - access log does not report any access at all whatsoever.

From the letsencrypt log:

```
2017-09-18 18:27:34,331:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.webroot:Creating root challenges validation dir at /var/www/example/.well-known/acme-challenge
2017-09-18 18:27:34,334:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.webroot:Attempting to save validation to /var/www/example/.well-known/acme-challenge/AUStfngCwdGL8Hel2jR0jG4wLZZjXi-s7AypLNWrECo
2017-09-18 18:27:34,335:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:Waiting for verification...
```

If I create `/var/www/example/.well-known/acme-challenge/AUStfngCwdGL8Hel2jR0jG4wLZZjXi-s7AypLNWrECo` manually and connect via firefox, I can connect without problems. Also then the nginx-access log gets filled.
Nginx error log is empty in both cases.

In case it is of help, my nginx config for the site looks like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name example.com;

location /.well-known {
    root /var/www/example;
}

location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

}

server {

listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
...

}
```

Honestly I am not really sure where to find any more clues as to what might be the matter.
Any of you have some ideas?

Comment: What is your command for certbot? Did you specify ```--webroot```?

Comment: My command is `certbot renew`. I tried adding `--webroot `, however to no success. I checked the following: 1) Certbot creates the necessary file. 2) I can access the file from my computer 3) My access is logged via nginx, letsencrypt is not logged. Therefore I suspect, that letsencrypt either doesnt even try to connect or somehow (how?) fails to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I got messages like `The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain ::` only if the my DNS changes weren't propagated to all DNS servers yet.

When you connect via Firefox to example.com/.well-known/ you are really go over the internet or is the address only known on your network?

If you do a `dig @8.8.8.8 example.com`, is the name resolved to to the correct IP address?

Comment: I found the problem. The A-Record was correct (thus my firefox connected properly), however the AAAA-Record was not. Apparently letsencrypt evaluates the ipv6 address.

Comment: Same here, @user2089648. The IPv6 connectivity on my server went down, and I needed to reboot to fix it. I didn't notice from my end, as I don't have IPv6 connectivity at my house!